# Error trying to include FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to include https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js in my js file however I get the error below. How do I fix the MIME type if that's the right thing to do?

"Refused to execute script from 'github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js'; because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. "

Comment: download that file and include it in your project.

Comment: this is the url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js  but it's not a CDN ya know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you follow that URL, you can see it's an HTML page, not the script itself. You either need to download that JS file, or use a different URL:

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js"/>
```

The project has a demo directory, you can find an example there:
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/tree/master/demo

Comment: Thanks, I understand I missed the obvious. I changed my source file to the link you gave me but still seeing this error "Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. " Any thoughts? Thanks for being helpful, I am just beginning to learn this.

Comment: @Aqua267 It's not the URL I gave you. The URL you currently use results in a 404 page. Copy the URL from my answer.